# Insert item to database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a problem with insert into statement..

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into FWINFOS (ID,Name,Gender,DateOfBirth,Race,WorkingPlace,PassportNO,DateOfExpire,Position,Photo) " +
                       "values('" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + 
                       "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + 
                       "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "',@Position,@Photo)", con);

conv_photo();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
con.Open();
int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
if (n > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
    loaddata();
    rno++;
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("No Insert");
```

> ERROR : Syntax Error INSERT INTO

Anyone can advise me? Please, Sorry for my bad English grammar.

Comment: Side comment: You've done a good job using a parameter for `Position`, how come you don't use one for `id`?

Comment: "having error" -> What error?

Comment: Yes like @Ic said, use parameterised queries, and also, could you give us the error ? Is the combobox returning a value ? Are you binding it correct in the first place ?

Comment: @lc., hold on, i opening my laptop

Comment: What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you are missing out a parameter in your query, try using this

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1 (id,Position) values (@id,@Position)";

cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@id", textBox1.Text);
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@Position", combobox1.selectedvalue);
```

**new updated**
-the position is the oleh db reserved words, try change to this query, put the cover to Position like below

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into FWINFOS (ID,Name,Gender,DateOfBirth,Race,WorkingPlace,PassportNO,DateOfExpire,[Position],Photo) " +
                   "values('" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + 
                   "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + 
                   "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "',@Position,@Photo)", con);
```

Comment: @ThamJunKai please tick my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed adding @Photo parameter in your code.

That is ok for testing purpose but you should never insert to database this way. This expose your system to a [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx). You should use parametrized queries where possible. Something like

```
int result=0;
using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection ("YourConnectionString"))
{
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into FWINFOS (ID,Name,Gender,DateOfBirth,Race,WorkingPlace,PassportNO,DateOfExpire,Position,Photo) values (@ID, @Gender, @DateOfBirth, @Race, @WorkingPlace, @PassportNO, @DateOfExpire, @Position, @Photo)", con);

        conv_photo();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox5.Text);
        // Specify all parameters like this
        try
        {   
          con.Open();
          result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()); 
        }

        catch( OledbException ex)
        {
             // Log error
        }
        finally
        {
           if (con!=null) con.Close();
            }
        }

if(result > 0)
     // Show success message
```

> Also note that OleDb parameters are positional, means you have to
>   specify them in the exact order as in your query. [OleDbParameter Class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx)

Comment: I have a coding for photo on below, but i never put it here.

Comment: You are specifying photo inside your SQL query but you are not binding a parameter for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
There is no value for parameter @Photo, and if your photo field is not nullable or empty
in database structure then how you can add null value in that.So make your data field 
nullable or pass value to parameter @Photo.I think it will solve your problem.

cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into FWINFOS (ID,Name,Gender,DateOfBirth,Race,WorkingPlace,PassportNO,DateOfExpire,Position,Photo) " +
                       "values('" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + 
                       "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + 
                       "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "',@Position,@Photo)", con);

conv_photo();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", assignvalue);
con.Open();
int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
if (n > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
    loaddata();
    rno++;
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("No Insert");
```